# Why is an integrable function zero outside a $σ$-finite subset?

Tags: measure-theory

When reading [a MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94486/fubinis-theorem-without-completeness-or-sigma-finiteness-conditions), I have the following questions:

Why is an integrable function (i.e. a $L^1$ function?) zero outside a $σ$-finite subset?

Is it equivalent to say the support of an integrable function a $\sigma$-finite subset? I guess the equivalence require the measure space to be complete?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the measure of each set $\{x\mid |f(x)|\geqslant1/n\}$ must be finite for $f$ to be integrable.

Comment: But can we say the function $f$'s support is $\sigma$-finite ? The support is defined to be the closure of the nonzero set. Is the closure of a $\sigma$-finte set is still $\sigma$-finite ?

Comment: @Hua The zero set is the union above, not the closure. Closure refers to a topology and we are working with measurable spaces here.

Comment: I guess you are right in this case. I checked the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) and found I overlooked a point that the domain may not be topological where the support is defined as closure. But indeed it interests me whether a closure of a $\sigma$-finite subset of a topological space is still $\sigma$-finite. :-)

Comment: Of course it's not. Consider the counting measure on real numbers with standard topology. Rational numbers is a $\sigma$-finite set but the closure is not.